# Extra files present when using a bootstrap enabled control?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I want to use [this bootstrap enabled timepicker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/), but I can't get the dropdown to appear when I click on the button. I'm very new to web development, so I assume I'm missing a step that is so obvious to everyone else that it isn't even mentioned in [the documentation](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/blob/gh-pages/README.md).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978093/bootstrap-datepicker-and-timepicker-not-working-when-added-to-wordpress-theme) mentions that there are "relevant css files" that need to go in the `css/bootstrap` folder. Is this true? What files are they?

So far I have done the following to install this control on my page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
    <link type="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-2.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
      <input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$('#timepicker1').timepicker();
$('#timepicker1').timepicker().on('show.timepicker', function(e) {
    console.log('The time is ' + e.time.value);
    console.log('The hour is ' + e.time.hour);
    console.log('The minute is ' + e.time.minute);
    console.log('The meridian is ' + e.time.meridian);
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I get the console log messages in Chrome when clicking on the button that should open the dropdown, so I know it's getting the click event properly.

If I look in the `bootstrap-timepicker/css` folder though, I see this file:

```
bootstrap-responsive.css
```

Do I need to do something with this file? There are also several other files in `bootstrap-timepicker/assets`, `bootstrap-timepicker/less`, and some of the other folders, but I'm not sure if these get compiled into the minified source later, or I need to somehow install them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
<link type="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
```

`link`'s attribute `type` should be `"text/css"` and `rel` should be `"stylesheet"`. Change it and it should work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
```